# Combobox fires action event when underlying data is modified

Tags: javafx, combobox, javafx-11

I've been puzzling over this one for a while now and just wanted to see if others had run into this problem before or if maybe I'm doing something wrong.

Given a javafx implementation in which we use a combobox whose items are set from an `ObservableArrayList` which can be updated, modified, replaced, etc. and a combobox with an action listener just logging out whenever it's triggered.

```
package sample;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.geometry.Orientation;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.ComboBox;
import javafx.scene.layout.FlowPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Main extends Application {

    ObservableList<String> theList = FXCollections.observableArrayList();

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception{
        primaryStage.setTitle("Sample");
        FlowPane root = new FlowPane(Orientation.VERTICAL);
        root.setVgap(20);

        List<String> initialColors = Arrays.asList("red", "green", "blue", "black");
        theList.addAll(initialColors);

        ComboBox<String> theComboBox = new ComboBox<>();
        theComboBox.setItems(theList);
        theComboBox.setOnAction( event -> {
            System.out.println(String.format("theComboBox action listener triggered, current value is %s", theComboBox.getValue()));
        });
        
        Button bttn1 = new Button("Press me");
        bttn1.setOnAction(event -> {
            List<String> someColors = Arrays.asList("red", "orange", "mauve", "pink", "blue", "salmon", "chiffon");
            System.out.println("About to issue setAll against observable list");
            theList.setAll(someColors);
        });

        root.getChildren().add(theComboBox);
        root.getChildren().add(bttn1);

        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root, 100, 150));
        primaryStage.show();

        System.out.println("Setting initial selection to \"blue\"");
        theComboBox.setValue("blue");

    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

I think the action event should only be triggered when the user changes the combobox through a direct action but I'm seeing the event trigger when the observablelist is modified.

We're using javafx version 11.0.2

Should I log this as a bug with Gluon?

EDIT: Updated example

In this example you can see that whenever the underlying data is modified via `setAll` the action event is triggered. This would be fine if the action event had some sort of way to differentiate between whether it's from a direct user interaction or from programmatic changes to the underlying data.

Other strange behaviour, the action event won't trigger if you select "black" and then hit the "press me" button and the combobox will then select pink because it's in the same position in the list - but then select red or even pink again and you'll get null, red, null and  null, pink, null respectively.

I'd expect the combobox to retain its value even if the selection is not present anymore and I also would not expect these events to be triggered when the observable list is being modified - if you needed/wanted to listen for events when the observable list is modified you can attach a listener directly to it instead.

Comment: [mcve] please ...

Comment: @kleopatra - is my example too minimal or too verbose?

Comment: please read the referenced help page and act accordingly :) your's isn't an example at all, it's just a snippet. That said: firing on setting items may fire if it triggers a value change, from sped: _ComboBox action, which is invoked whenever the ComboBox value property is changed_

Comment: Your example is not reproducible. Post something we can copy, paste, and run *as is* to reproduce the problem.

Comment: Gotcha, will do

Comment: The example doesn't demonstrate what you say in the title: "Combobox ***only*** fires action event when underlying data is modified". (My emphasis.) The action event is also fired when the user selects a new value, as expected. I don't find this behavior too surprising; when you call `setAll()` you remove all existing elements and then replace it with the new ones. At the point where there are no elements, the selected element becomes null. If you use a less heavy-handed approach to update the combo, you will probably find it works as desired.

Comment: Note also you can always set a flag when you're updating the combo box items, and check the flag in the `onAction` handler.

Comment: @James_D - omg I don't know why I added "only" to the title, my bad.

So, yes, the use-case is heavy handed but for my actual use case it's necessary and valid. I'm going off of this documentation, let me know if it's invalid please; https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/ComboBox.html

Particularly: "The value property is not constrained to items contained within the items list - it can be anything as long as it is a valid value of type T." and the other points listed after it

Does this not seem to be contradictory to the behaviour I'm seeing here?

Comment: Changes in the value are not necessarily the same as action events being fired, though. What happens if you just register a listener with the `valueProperty`? If that shows the same behavior, then I'd consider that a bug, as it's not consistent with the API docs.

Comment: Also, thanks for the suggestion of using a flag variable, I came to the same conclusion and that's what I'm doing now but I'm still baffled as to why action events fire when the items are set, I'd think that an action event should occur only when the value changes and that the value should remain until the user selects a new value from the dropdown.

Comment: Actually, looking again, even if an action event is fired when the list changes, the value shouldn't be changing, according to the docs. So this seems like a bug.

Comment: Seems the same to me too - I set an event listener on the valueproperty just now using the example above and although initially it seemed to be ok, after manually selecting a new value I started getting the "null, colour, null" behaviour from before.

Does the javafx project have an issue tracker somewhere?

Comment: @James_D _Changes in the value are not necessarily the same as action events being fired_ as per doc of onAction, they are: whenever the value changes (for whatever reason), the action handler must be notified

Comment: @OP - there are several interwoven issues here: a) expecting an action to be in any way related to user interaction is wrong b) the doc you cited  is logically inconsistent (old debate ;) - only the first sentence holds, 4th is plain wrong, 2 and 3 are different from what's implemented c) basically the invariant is value == selectionItem which must hold always (including uncontained values) d) effects of modifying the items is .. ill-specified: at the end of day, it's the selectionModel that defines it .. in its implementation (which is inconsistent ;)

Comment: .. cont'd: e) clearly bugs: not firing an action if the value changes or firing multiple actions for a single change f) there are open issues around uncontained values g) please let us know when your bug report hits public (don't yet see it)

Comment: @James_D fyi: the [bug reported](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8263942) by Sean was closed - because it's based on the incorrect expectation that action trigger is in any way related to user interaction. Intent to re-open (or re-report) with the actual misbehavior on action after setAll: either not even if there is a value change (initial black) - or twice if there is no value change (initial blue)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just to wrap this up, take a look through the comments on the question for more detail.

We think this is a bug in javafx 11.0.2 - I've filed a bug report through the openjdk jira.

A workaround for now is to set a flag boolean variable and only perform actions within the listener when it is true.

something as simple as adding:

```
private boolean actionEventsOn = true;
```

```
theComboBox.setOnAction( event -> {
    if(actionEventsOn){
        System.out.println(String.format("theComboBox action listener triggered, current value is %s", theComboBox.getValue()));
    }
});
```

```
bttn1.setOnAction(event -> {
    List<String> someColors = Arrays.asList("red", "orange", "mauve", "pink", "blue", "salmon", "chiffon");
    System.out.println("About to issue setAll against observable list");
    actionEventsOn = false;
    theList.setAll(someColors);
    actionEventsOn = true;
});
```

This should prevent action events triggering unnecessarily.

Comment: the bug is _not_ what [you reported](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8263942) it (that's why it's closed ;) but: is a) _not_ firing if the value changes b) firing _multiple_ times for a single selection change

Comment: commented the issue explaining the _real_ misbehavior - either to re-open with focus on the real issue, or open a new with references to the closed and this QA (not my call, will do the one or other :)

Comment: If my base assumption of the behaviour is wrong it is because the documentation that I linked earlier is wrong. At the very least that should be updated. I'm honestly over this issue, if the team that works on this wants to fix it they can or they can just ignore it and the javafx framework can keep on keeping on.

Comment: the doc you cited has nothing to do with modifying the items ;) from all bullets, only 2. talks about modification of the _items_ - "the items are cleared" - which is not the case in your example, all others talk about selection changes.